# Cannot read property 'top' of undefined (script conflict?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script like:

pagination.js

```
var busy = false;
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
        jQuery('#scrollUp').stop().animate({
            opacity: 0.05
        }, 400)
    } else {
        jQuery('#scrollUp').stop().animate({
            opacity: 0.00
        }, 400)
    }
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() > jQuery('#main_content').offset().top + jQuery('#main_content').height() - 50 && !busy) {
        busy = true;
        link = jQuery('.pagination .nextpage').attr('href');
        if (typeof link != 'undefined') {
            var params = 'smt_layout=' + jQuery('body').attr('layout') + '&ajaxpage=1';
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                data: params,
                url: link,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != "") {
                        jQuery('.pagination .nextpage').parent().append('<span class="thispage">Page ' + jQuery('.pagination .nextpage').attr('alt') + '</span>');
                        jQuery('.pagination .nextpage').remove();
                        jQuery("#main_content").append(data['content']);
                        busy = false
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
jQuery('#scrollUp').live('mouseenter', function () {
    jQuery(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.1
    }, "slow")
}).live('mouseout', function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 300) var o = 0.05;
    else var o = 0.00;
    jQuery(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: o
    }, "slow")
});
jQuery('#scrollUp').live('click', function () {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 1200);
});
```

I'm using a Magnific Popup on Photonic Gallery Wordpress Plugin:

[magnific.js](https://pastebin.com/p8C8BSTs)

and I get an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined at pagination.js:1

Does it look like a jQuery conflict? Could you please let me know how can I resolve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you just ask this same question not too long ago in a different post?

Comment: tough gig pasting minimized code

Comment: Ack.  Please _format your code_.  As-is, it's completely illegibile / untraceable.

Comment: Please provide all code necessary to reproduce the issue.  In this case, we’ll need to see the HTML. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It's failing on this: `jQuery('#main_content').offset().top`.

Make sure:

- You run `jQuery(document).ready()` before setting these handlers.
- You have a DOM element with an id of `main_content`.

Answer (score 0):

That's the function in which the script is implemented:

```html
function headtext() {
   if(
    (is_archive()&&is_day()&&$this->get( 'seo', 'day' ))||
    (is_archive()&&is_month()&&$this->get( 'seo', 'month' ))||
    (is_archive()&&is_year()&&$this->get( 'seo', 'year' ))||
    (is_category()&&$this->get( 'seo', 'category' ))||
    (is_tag()&&$this->get( 'seo', 'tag' ))||
    (is_author()&&$this->get( 'seo', 'author' ))||
    (is_search()&&$this->get( 'seo', 'search' ))
   ) {
    ?><meta name="robots" content="noindex" /><?php
   }
   if ($this->get( 'general', 'favicon' )) 
    echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="' . $this->get( 'general', 'favicon' ) . '" type="image/x-icon" />' . "\n";
   if ($this->get( 'integration', 'rss' )) {
    echo '<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS Feed" href="' . $this->get( 'integration', 'rss' ) . '" />' . "\n";
   }
   
   if ($this->get( 'layout', 'pagination' )) { ?>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/js/pagination.js"></script>
   <?php } ?>
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/css/wide.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:1024px)" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/css/wide.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/css/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:240px) and (max-width:639px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/css/tablet.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:640px) and (max-width:1023px)" />
    <?php if ($this->get( 'integration', 'ecwidcss' )) { ?>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/css/ecwid.css" type="text/css"  />
    <?php } ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/css/shortcode.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/js/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <?php
   if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

     <?php
      $this->block_slider_config();
     ?>
     jQuery(".menus .children").addClass('sub-menu');
     <?php
      $this->block_menu_config("menus");
     ?>
     jQuery('textarea[name="comment"]').each(function(){
      jQuery(this).attr('name','<?php echo $_SESSION['commentinput']; ?>');
     });
     
    });
   </script>
   <?php
  }
```